# imported a populated table on to postgresql but I need the model in Django . What to do?

Tags: django, postgresql, model

I have a set of populated tables (country,region town etc) that I have imported onto Pgadmin (postgresql) but I need the models in Django now so that I can work on those tables. However, like I said, these were tables with data, so if I write the model definition in Django, it will either destroy my tables by overwriting them (leaving them empty) or it will give an error.

I prefer to work now with models, but can't create them because the tables already exist.
What can I do? I know you could say, well, you should have first defined the models. Well, no, because the three tables are linked by multiple composite primary keys and actually I got the code for the model once the tables have been imported to the pgadmin, and the model definition was quite complex.
If you are curious to see how a model definition looks here it goes:

`

```
class Localidades(models.Model):
    id_localidad = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_region = models.SmallIntegerField()
    id_pais = models.SmallIntegerField()
    id_idioma = models.SmallIntegerField()
    nombre_localidad = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    x = models.FloatField()
    y = models.FloatField()
    exacto = models.SmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'localidades'
        unique_together = (('id_localidad', 'id_region', 'id_pais', 'id_idioma'),)
```

`
I did not even want to try, can't afford to have my tables destroyed.

Comment: From docs [Models Meta](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/options/): *managed ... If False, no database table creation, modification, or deletion operations will be performed for this model. This is useful if the model represents an existing table or a database view that has been created by some other means. This is the only difference when managed=False. All other aspects of model handling are exactly the same as normal*. If you don't believe it set up a test database and verify.

Comment: If you want to be safe use `pg_dump ... -t <table_1> -t <table_2> -t <table_3>` to dump the table definitions and data before doing any changes.

Comment: You should read the rest of that doc section also.